OpenVPN error "unrecognized option or missing parameters" with high-utf characters (ÿþd )
I have an openVPN client config file that has been provided me by an entity to whom I need to connect professionally. After decrypting it and checking that the contents look ok, I tried to connect to their network, but got the following error:
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in cyd3.ovpn:1: ÿþd (2.6.12)
Use --help for more information.

This is a combination of characters that is absent from my configurations file, and no search I was able to perform returned this string as a necessary OpenVPN parameter. This persists after a restart and config file re-download and decryption.
What is going on? What can cause this issue and how can I address it?
